# How to add files from outside of the Maven project to the ZIP distribution?

Tags: java, maven

I would like to add a file from outside of the Maven project folder to the ZIP that is generated when assembling. How can I do this in the bin.xml file?

```
Some folder
  -Maven Project folder
  -Random folder
      -File I want to add
```

What I've tried:

```
<fileSet>
       <directory>../${project.basedir}</directory>
       <includes>
           <include>Random folder/File I want to add</include>
       </includes>
 </fileSet>
```

EDIT: Other things I've tried:

```
 ../${basedir}
 ${project.basedir}/../
```

Comment: That makes the build not reproducible / executable on other systems. Why would you do that? What kind of file/data is in the "random folder" so that it cannot be added to the project source itself?

Comment: @JasperHuzen  Nothing specific. This is hypothetical.  I guess an example of such a case is when you have your maven project inside a workspace folder. How would you include your .git folder in the ZIP assembly?

Comment: you can use the [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html) to control what's inside of the zip file. The best is using only stuff from inside of your own project, or dependencies through the maven dependency system.

Comment: @JasperHuzen I already have an assembly descriptor in my src folder but how would I access directories outside of the project folder? Is there a way to go one directory up and then choose said folder/file? I've looked on stackoverflow/google but haven't found anything helpful.